# Problem on implementing Google Coral Accelerator

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqTLkw1IenI&t=237s

It shows how to implement the Google Coral to improve object detection. However, I have this error when running step `from tflite_support import metadata5`:

```
'MetadataPopulator' object has no attribute 'load_metadata_and_associated_files'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.